# How to retrieve huge data from DynamoDB efficiently?

Tags: database, dynamodb-queries

We are developing IOT application, in which we are receiving custom route geological data from the IOT device at every one minute and storing it in `DynamoDB` having size 500-600bytes.

Now we want to show report for every device including data for every minute or every 15 minutes for past 7 days.

**What we want to achieve:**

Since we want to show all `geological` points on the map, we want to develop single API which returns 7 days of data for a given device.

**Problem:**

We have approx **6MB**(600bytes*10080 minutes in 7 days) data for a single device and `DynamoDB` query returns only **1MB** of data in a single query, we have tried pagination in `DynamoDB` query which takes **6 queries** to gather all the data which takes a lot of time and API gets timed out.

Comment: What is the provisioned read capacity of your table or index?

Comment: As of now, we are still in development so we have kept it 1 only

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have 1 provisioned read capacity unit you can only read about 8kb/sec from the table. Try switching to on demand billing or increasing the RCU.